# I want the code to use my phone book contacts in any of my application

Tags: android

I want the code to use my phone book contacts in any of my application means I want to get the code to my phone book contact data so that i can select any contact from it and use its number and other details that are stored in that contact

Answer (score 1):

try with this dude :) best of luck

and this is code of class

```
 public class ReadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private ListView contactsList;

        private Context cntx;
        private Constant constants;

        static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID, // 0
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
            Contacts.STARRED, // 2
            Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED, // 3
            Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE, // 4
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID, // 5
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, // 6
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, // 7
        };

        private long contactId;
        private String display_name;
        private String phoneNumber;

        private ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>contactWrap = new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>();
        private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>map = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>();

        private ContactsAdapter adapter;

        private DataController controller;

        public ReadContacts(Context cntx, ListView contactList) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cntx = cntx;
            constants = new Constant();
            this.contactsList = contactList;

            controller = DataController.getInstance(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
                 constants.displayProgressDialog(cntx, "Loading Contacts...", "Please Wait");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
            {
            try {
                String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                        + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                        + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

                Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                        null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

                int colorcounter = 0;
                String[] colorcounter_array = { "#91A46B", "#8BB6B5", "#CAA973", "#8DA6C8","#D19B8D"};

                int color_string;
                for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
                {
    //              contactWrap.clear();
                    try {
                        contactId = 0;
                        String hasPhone = "";
                        display_name = "";
                        phoneNumber = "";

                        c.moveToPosition(i);

                        contactId =  c.getLong(0);
                        display_name = c.getString(1);
                        hasPhone = c.getString(7);

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                            hasPhone = "true";
                        else
                            hasPhone = "false" ;

                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                        {
                            Cursor phones = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                            {
                                int indexPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
                                String phoneType =  phones.getString(indexPhoneType);

                                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                                String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                                if (colorcounter < 5) 
                                {
                                    color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                    colorcounter++;
                                } else {
                                    colorcounter = 0;
                                    color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                    colorcounter++;
                                }
                                contactWrap.add(new ContactsWrapper(contactId, display_name, phoneNumber,lookupKey,false,color_string));
                            }
    //                      map.put(contactId, new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>(contactWrap));
                            phones.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  
                }
                controller.contactWrapper = contactWrap;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            constants.dismissDialog();

            adapter = new ContactsAdapter(cntx);
            contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

and this is my contact wrapper class

```
 public class ContactsWrapper {

    private long contactId;
    private String displayName,displayNumber,lookUp;
    public boolean checked = true;
    int color_string;

    public ContactsWrapper(long contactId, String displayName, String displayNumber, String lookUp, boolean checked,int color_string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.contactId = contactId;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.displayNumber = displayNumber;
        this.lookUp = lookUp;
        this.checked = checked;
        this.color_string =color_string;
    }

    public String getLookUp() {
        return lookUp;
    }

    public int getColor_string() {
        return color_string;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public long getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayNumber() {
        return displayNumber;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `content provider` of `COntacts` app in your application. 
go through [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)